# How to replace a string with a component (vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have strings that contains `###` and I am replacing with array values. Now I want to use them with a component, I created the component and it works but I don't know how to use it in the strings. I don't want to wrap them manually because I don't know how the strings will be, it can have several `###`. If it has 2 `###`, options will have 2 subArrays.

What is the better way to do it?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/tsobh4nu/

```js
Vue.component('opt', {
  template: `<label>
                <span class="bold" v-for="(str,idx) in options">
                     {{str + " / "}}
                </span>
             </label>`,
  props:{options: Array}
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    str: "I have ### and you have a ###.",
      options: [
        ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
        ['XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ']
      ]
  },
  computed:{
   replacedStr(){
     let newStr = this.str;
      this.options.forEach(option=>{
       newStr = newStr.replace('###',this.concatenateOptions(option));
      })
      return newStr;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    concatenateOptions(strArr) {
      let separator = "";
      let strOptions = "";
      strArr.forEach(word => {
        strOptions += separator  + word;
        separator = " / ";
      });
      return strOptions;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>I want something like this, but using components: </p>
  {{replacedStr}}
  <br>
  <hr>
  My Components:<br>
  <opt :options="options[0]"></opt>
  <br>
  <opt :options="options[1]"></opt>
</div>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Is `###` the name of the component? If so, you can use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Comment: no, it's where I'm going to replace the component. I saw that example and I think it's different. They know where to put `<component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>`. In my case I don't know, It's more dynamic.

Answer (score 7):

This is more general, but I hope it will help someone. Add a dynamic component in your template: `<component v-bind:is="processedHtml"></component>`.

Then add a computed method:

```
computed: {
    processedHtml () {
        let html = this.html.replace('[Placeholder]', '<my-component></my-component>');
        return {
            template: '<div>' + html + '</div>'
        }
     }
}
```

Where `<my-component>` is your custom component and the `this.html` is your HTML content that contains the placeholder `[Placeholder]`.

It is important to return an element that has one root node. That's why the return is wrapped with `<div>`.

Read more advanced tutorial about this issue [here in my blog](https://fullstack-tutorials.com/vue/vue-replace-text-with-component-with-props). For example, to pass props to `<my-component>`

Comment: I've been unsuccessful in using arbitrary html in v-bind:is.  The documentation says that you can only use the name of a component or a components option object.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components
What version of vue are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I just experienced the same issue. I had an element that needed to display the current count of an item. The current count came from the store and was constantly changing. I used v-text. I know this is pretty situation specific, but hopefully it helps someone down the line.

```
<P id="results_count" v-text="current_count"></P>
```

and in the data portion of the component I had a property named current_count that was updated via methods.