# Bold word in a text

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I would like to put in bold key words found in a paragraph.

Here my code for the moment :

```
       <div v-for="item in data.description" :key="item">
          {{item}}
       </div>
```

Item is all the sentences of my description.

On my interface I have for example the following text:

> 125.475 mhz will not be avbl. pilots requesting flight information   During this period may contact london control on the notified h24
> Frequencies in the aip page enr 2.1

I would like to put in bold the word "frequencies" just in the sentence where there is this word.

Do you know how to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you get that text from? Can't you update the source (in database or something like that)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257153/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-component-vue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=vue+replace+string+"v-for"+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: We need to know more about your situation. Where is the content of your block coming from? What tools do you have available to change the text? (I assume you know that you need to wrap the words in a `<b>...</b>` tag pair.)

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think picking unanswered duplicates (with regard to having a picked answer, or at least decently upvoted) is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
{{item}}
```

with

```
<span v-html="item.replaceAll('frequencies', '<b>frequencies</b>')"></span>
```